Convert a "tecplot" mesh file into "ansys fluent" (.msh)
I have a mesh with a "tecplot" format but i need to use it in "ansys fluent", I found a github repository called "meshio", but i didn't understand how to use it, or maybe it's does not even work , is there any other solutions!!
the "meshio" was difficult to understand

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
